# Validating association's attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :member

  before_validation :able_to_upload

  private

  def able_to_upload
    self.errors[:member] << 'can not upload photo.' if self.member.credits < 50
  end
end
```

I have a Member model with `credits` attribute. Members with 50 credits or higher should be able to upload photos. How should I validate `credits` attribute when member uploading a photo? I came up with this solution but I'm wondering if there is any better way to do this. Adding errors on a validation callback right way to do this? Or should I create a virtual attribute and validate `credits` with a proc?

Edit: Although this solution works, I have created a "Chargeable" module for a more generic solution which feels just right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good solution.

For reasons I didn't remind, you should use

```
 def validate
 end
```

instead of `before_validation`